# Why does this native event obj have the .currentTarget property as null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I console.logged a jquery event object and a native event object. In jquery the currentTarget points to the element, the event occured at, however the native version is null. Why is the native currentTarget null and how can I fix this?

```
        let child=$(".child").get(0);

        child.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            console.log(e);
            this.style.backgroundColor="blue";
        },false);

        $(".child").on("click",function(e){
            console.log(e);
        });
```

Comment: If you change it to `console.log(e.currentTarget)` you see the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Native `currentTarget` is probably implemented using a getter, so the value doesn't appear when you log the event object.